# Accumulate does not work with sum, but does work with equivalent lambda function. Why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools, accumulate

I was playing around with the accumulate function, and I thought that `accumulate(<int[]>,sum)` would yield a cumulative sum. However, running the following code results in an error.

```
from itertools import accumulate
print([*accumulate([1,2,3],sum)])
```

Specifically, I get `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`. On the other hand, running the same code with a lambda function that does the exact same thing leads to the expected result.

```
from itertools import accumulate
print([*accumulate([1,2,3],lambda *args:sum(args))])
# [1, 3, 6]
```

When I run this code using a named, custom function which does the same thing, I get yet another bizarre result.

```
from itertools import accumulate    
def my_sum(*args): return sum(args)
print([*accumulate([1,2,3]),my_sum])
#[1, 3, 6, <function my_sum at 0x7fd57139caf0>]
```

It's not clear what is leading to the difference in behavior. `sum,my_sum,` and the anonymous function are are of the type "function", so the type alone isn't determining things. I also did the following to see if I could get any other lead; the only difference I noticed is that `sum` is a built in function.

```
print(lambda *args:sum(args),my_sum,sum,sep='\n')
# <function <lambda> at 0x7fd57139cb80>
# <function my_sum at 0x7fd57139cc10>
# <built-in function sum>
```

So what's going on here?

Comment: Passing `sum` directly is equivalent to using `sum(*args)` instead of `sum(args)` in your lambda function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate): for `itertools.accumulate(iterable[, func, *, initial=None])`

> If `func` is supplied, it should be a function of two arguments. Elements of the input `iterable` may be any type that can be accepted as arguments to `func`. (For example, with the default operation of addition, elements may be any addable type including `Decimal` or `Fraction`.)

`sum()` does accept two arguments, but the first argument *must* be an iterable, and the second is the start value. [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum)

Let's see what `accumulate()` passes to its `func` argument by printing the args in `my_sum()`

```
def my_sum(*args):
    print(args)
    return sum(args)

accumulate([1, 2, 3], my_sum)
# (1, 2)
# (3, 3)
```

So `accumulate()` passes the last accumulated value and the next number to `func`. Since the first argument to `sum()` must be iterable (which an `int` is not), you get that error.

Your lambda is *not* equivalent to `sum()`: `sum()` takes *one iterable* and returns the sum of its elements. Your lambda takes *any number of arguments* and returns the sum of those arguments. To test this, see what you get when you do `sum([1, 2, 3])`, and `my_sum([1, 2, 3])`.

In your final example you have a typo. You didn't pass `my_sum` to `accumulate()`. You created a list containing the result of `accumulate([1, 2, 3])`, and then the function `my_sum`. Fix it to `print([*accumulate([1,2,3], my_sum)])` and you get the same output as the lambda case.

Note that providing no `func` behaves as if `func=operator.add` and will give you a cumulative sum.

```
>>> accumulate([1, 2, 3])
[1, 3, 6]
```

Comment: Thank you for a thorough answer! I seem to have assumed in the back of my head that `sum(<int>,<int>)` worked